# How to join a specific table row?

Tags: mysql

```
table_one

+------+-------------+
| id   | cool        |
+------+-------------+
| 1    | 1.58        |
| 2    | 8.88        |
+------+-------------+

table_two

+------+-------------+
| id   | okies       |
+------+-------------+
| 1    | 2.15        |
| 2    | 7.50        |
+------+-------------+

table_result

+------+-------------------+
| id   | result            |
+------+-------------------+
| 1    | 1.58 (min value)  |
| 2    | 7.50 (min value)  |
+------+-------------------+
```

Howdy, I am somewhat familiar with mysql. I am using the `least()` function to find the minimum value between `table_one` and `table_two`:

```
INSERT INTO table_result (id, result)
select table_one.id, least(table_one.cool, table_two.okies) val
from table_one 
  join table_two on table_one.id = table_two.id

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id), result=VALUES(result)
```

This code works perfectly, except I do not want to (evaluate) get the minimum value of all the table rows (id `1` and id `2`). I want to evaluate/target a specific row id (ex: id `2` only!).

I tried adding `WHERE id = 2` but I kept getting errors.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Perhaps you just need to alias the `id` column in your `where` critera...

Comment: @sgeddes thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What errors are you getting? Perhaps you just need to alias the id
>   column in your where critera...  – [sgeddes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073631/sgeddes)

The error I was getting was **Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous**. Turns out after researching this error, I needed to specify which table id, as both tables have id.

```
INSERT INTO table_result (id, result)
select table_one.id, least(table_one.cool, table_two.okies) val
from table_one 
  join table_two on table_one.id = table_two.id
  WHERE table_one.id = 2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id), result=VALUES(result)
```